# Ubuntu not installing. Stuck at black blank screen

Tags: 14.04, boot, uefi

I have followed the steps in the website. I have burned the iso file into the usb drive. When i try to install from usb drive ( uefi boot) I am getting a blink, then stuck at black blank screen.
My laptop is: hp envy notebook

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Disable FastBoot, QuickBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology in your BIOS. When booting press the hotkey for boot device selection (should be F9 for your device). Select the UEFI Ubuntu boot entry.

A good page to get more info about UEFI is [UEFI Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, even with fastboot, quickboot and SWT off, still the UEFI boot does not succeed, and you get a command line, and you can when not know what to do, end up with a black screen.

To exit *that* black screen, press power button for several (10+?) seconds.
With internal battery on modern laptops, one cannot resort to switch off by removing the battery as last resort.

I am mentioning this, because none of the answers to questions "stuck at blank black screen" mention how to exit that screen.